# How to write global route filter middleware to redirect the user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I understand in Laravel 5.3 they have deprecated Route Filters in favor of middleware. This is discussed [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l53-routeserviceprovider-update?page=1).

I am trying to do something similar but instead of defining a Route pattern I want to define a "filter" where I check the logged in user for a certain condition and redirect the user if this condition is not met. I want this filter to be globally applied to the app.

How can I do this? I only see documentation for the Route::pattern method but Route::filter does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel Middlewares like this:

To create a new middleware, use the make:middleware Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckUserAge
```

And your `CheckUserAge.php` class should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckUserAge
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if (auth()->user->age <= 20) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
  }

}
```

If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
  'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
  'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
  'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
  'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
  // insert your middleware here <--------------
  'checkUserAge' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserAge::class,
];
```

> Out of the box, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your  `routes/web.php` file by the `RouteServiceProvider`.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
  'web' => [
      \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
      \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
      \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
      \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
      \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserAge::class, // <------- add here too
  ],
];
```

> See more about [Middlewares in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you. Thanks!